# Why does oxforddictionaries.com not use a comma after the abbreviations 'i.e.' and 'e.g.'?

Tags: punctuation, commas, abbreviations

At [oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/), they don't use a comma after 'e.g.' and 'i.e.'.

**Period is required after 'i.e.' here in BrE.**

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/e.g.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/i.e.

But we would use a comma after 'for example' and 'that is' in a sentence.

So why is the comma omitted after each abbreviation? This, logically, does not make sense.

Comment: To save space, perhaps?

Comment: That doesn't make the punctuation correct, however. They are being remiss, then, in showing proper punctuation usage. It certainly cannot be to save space.

Comment: Because it's not in a sentence, that's why. Though using or not using a comma is a style issue, not a dictionary entry issue.

Answer (score 5):

[The Oxford Manual of Style (section 5.3)](https://books.google.com/books?id=gDzQklrA8MUC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=%22To+avoid+double+punctuation,+no+comma+follows+i.e.+and+e.g.+in+OUP+style.%22&source=bl&ots=w_sIE9RFXm&sig=HWcqUSkOd7p3k3jpklqAZd9i5Go&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQpoLEk8nPAhWFdx4KHW24DFMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22To%20avoid%20double%20punctuation%2C%20no%20comma%20follows%20i.e.%20and%20e.g.%20in%20OUP%20style.%22&f=false) states:

> To avoid double punctuation, no comma follows *i.e.* and *e.g.* in OUP
>   style.

The Oxford Manual of Style, Oxford University Press, 2002

Comment: Have they updated this? *The Chicago Manual of Style* went back and forth on the issue and is currently *with* the comma.

Comment: The OUP tend to go their own way, and I don't have the latest edition.